# I want to repeat applying, canceling, applying, and canceling events with the same key operation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used to make my own bookmarklet, and now I'm implementing a script that can apply the following CSS so that it can be called by a keydown action of a user script, also as an experiment.

```
//Brightness adjustment, sepia adjustment
$(function() {
    let s = document.createElement("style");
    $(window).keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 122) { // CTRL+F11
            s.textContent = `html{filter: sepia(25%) brightness(90%);}
body{background-color:#F9F9F9;}`;
            document.head.appendChild(s);
            return false;
            //}else
            //if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode==122){ // CTRL+F11
            //location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```

I wanted to implement this code so that I could unapply CSS with the same keydown. Is that possible?

As a flow of operation,

`if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 122) {`

↓

Apply CSS

↓

`if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 122) {`

↓

Remove CSS

↓

`if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 122) {`

↓

Apply CSS

↓

`if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 122) {`

↓

Remove CSS

↓

repetition

Is the above process possible?

please tell me.

Happy new year.

Comment: keep a reference to the element and use removeChild()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible!

I assume you know to capture key bindings as you mentioned above:

```
if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 122) { ...
```

There is a JavaScript Based Library named jQuery (It can also be done with plain JS) but everything becomes easy with jQuery [https://jquery.com/], even `$.ajax` is a part of jQuery.

- You have mentioned `html{filter: sepia(25%) brightness(90%);} body{background-color:#F9F9F9;}` above. Instead of writing this code in `s.context =` , define these as css classes [Suppose you name the class `class-toggler`]
- Then, write the jQuery code using the `toggleClass()` function
- Here is how the`toggleClass()` function is to be used. Let us assume you want to apply filters on an element with `id="changeMyCSS"`. **Do not identify an element with a css classname in this case unless you are sure you won't be wrong as, we are going to add/remove CSS classes.**

  `if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 122) {
  $("#changeMyCSS").toggleClass("class-toggler");
  }`

More documentation on this function is at: https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

You can also read the addClass() and removeClass() functions at: https://api.jquery.com/addClass/#addClass-className and https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/#removeClass-className

*If you are unable to understand this answer completely, reply to it and I'll try to explain it in more detail*